# WPF DatagridTemplateColumn remove border space

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have defined a wpf datagrid template column with a cell editing template and a cell template, which works as expected.

The problem i have is the following: when editing a value in the cell, a (blue) border shows up.

How do i make this border dissapear?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the error i was chasing for, was seated somewhere else (so this question is kind of obsolete).